# How to get access token claims in a Blazor Server app using OIDC?

Tags: c#, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor server application that uses OIDC, the following code can access the authentication state and user claims.

```cs
@code {
    [Inject] AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var claims = authState.User.Claims;
    }
}
```

`claims` contain the following
[image: claims]

However, the access token returned from the OIDC provider had many more claims such as `scope`, `client_id`, `aud`, etc.

How to access all claims in the access token from a Blazor Server component?

Answer (score 1):

by default the OpenIDConnect handler will filter out and only include some specific claims. To map other claims, then you need to map them one by one using

```
AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
     options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("myclaim", "myclaim");
     options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
     ...
```

See this resource [Mapping, customizing, and transforming claims in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)